# Azure function error on startup: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have 2 azure function project in my solution.
When I startup multiple projects from Visual Studio and start both azure functions projects, I have an error message

```
Cannot access a disposed object. 
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'
```

But when i run separatly each azure function projet. I have no error.
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem.
The port is already taken (busy) so it s not possible to run 2 azure functions on the same port.
You can easily configure the host port via the properties page via debug tab then Application Arguments

```
host start --pause-on-error --port 7072
```

This is a article that explain this in details
https://dev.to/azure/debugging-multiple-azure-functions-apps-at-the-same-time-1ka4

Note: If you upgrade to the Azure function V3, the error message is more explicit

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  // ...
</Project>
```

Et voilà ;)